# Is it possible to run JUnit Theories in parallel?

Tags: performance, junit4

There are a lot of questions on how to run JUnit tests in parallel on SO. However, I don't think there's one about Theories specifically. If it's already the case, please accept my apologies and point this ignorant to the right place. :-)

I've found [this very helpful article](http://hwellmann.blogspot.be/2009/12/running-parameterized-junit-tests-in.html) about doing the same for Parameterized.

For the Theories runner however things are different. Each theory method seems to be running single-threaded for all generated combinations. As such it makes little difference to set a multi-threaded scheduler.

Unfortunately in my case it won't be very practical to use Parameterized either - because there are way too much permutations to be generated upfront. And honestly, I'd rather have JUnit do this stuff. :-)

Has somebody already tackled this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the apidocs for junit-toolbox over here](http://junit-toolbox.googlecode.com/git-history/31ca33755e987012dc9e93ef92fb8fb6dab3ff21/javadoc/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/ParallelRunner.html) for `ParallelRunner`:

> An extension of the JUnit Theories runner, which executes all @Test methods concurrently. Furthermore all calls to @Theory methods with different parameter assignments are executes concurrently too.

Comment: Did you even read it? Why do you think it is not for theories? The ParallelRunner is even derived from org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories...

Comment: Yes I did read it. :-) But the example is about '@Test' annotated methods. I'll have a try immediately. the bounty is yours if it runs '@Theory' annotated methods too.

Comment: Quick hacks in our code indicate this IS working !!!! :-) It almost reduced the execution time in half. I stand corrected ! I've removed the earlier comment - which is wrong - and voted up instead of down - which was obviously the wrong thing also. MANY THANKS INDEED !